# Вопрос касательно проблемы с тэгом <div>

Tags: css, html

[Есть код](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeZGdR).

```css
body {
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
}
.wrap {
  color: #7B68EE;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  font-family: arial;
}
.leftstr {
  height: 410px;
  font-size: 150%;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}
.rightstr {
  height: 410px;
  font-size: 150%;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
}
p {
  margin: 10%;
}
.subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Мой первый сайт</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>My first site</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="leftstr">
    <p>Duis te feugifacilisi. Duis autem dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit au gue duis dolore
      te feugat nulla facilisi. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci taion ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex en commodo consequat. Duis te feugifacilisi per suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex en commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightstr">
    <p>Duis te feugifacilisi. Duis autem dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit au gue duis dolore
      te feugat nulla facilisi. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci taion ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex en commodo consequat. Duis te feugifacilisi per suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex en commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="subtitle">
    <p>Смотреть предыдущие</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

У меня параграф "смотреть предыдущие" совмещен с сестринским элементом. Я бы хотел, чтобы он (`<p>`) был отдельным блоком и не сливался с остальными блоками. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про параметры [padding](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding) и [margin](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin).

```css
body {
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
}

.wrap {
  color: #7B68EE;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  font-family: arial;
}

.leftstr {
  min-height: 410px;
  font-size: 150%;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}

.rightstr {
  min-height: 410px;
  font-size: 150%;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
}

p {
  margin: 10%;
}

.subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px; /* устанавливаем внутрений отступ сверху */
  clear: both;
}

.subtitle p {
  margin-top: 10px; /* устанавливаем внешний отступ сверху */
  display: inline-block; /* меняем тип отображения елемента */
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Мой первый сайт</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
   <h1>My first site</h1>
  </div>
      <div class="leftstr">
      <p>Duis te feugifacilisi. Duis autem dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie 
      consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et 
      iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit au gue duis dolore
      te feugat nulla facilisi. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci taion 
      ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex en commodo consequat. Duis te 
      feugifacilisi per suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex en commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightstr">
      <p>Duis te feugifacilisi. Duis autem dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie 
      consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et 
      iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit au gue duis dolore
      te feugat nulla facilisi. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci taion 
      ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex en commodo consequat. Duis te 
      feugifacilisi per suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex en commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
               <div class="subtitle">
                  <p>Смотреть предыдущие</p>
               </div>
</body>
</html>
```